# discord.js how to send a detected memory leak to a channel?

Tags: memory-leaks, discord.js

So i get a memory leak in console from my discord bot (discord.js), so is there a way to send a message in a channel when a memory leak happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  // code which causes memory leak here
}
catch(err) {
  client.channels.get('CHANNEL ID').send('Error occured: ' + err.message);
}
```